# Is it possible to setup React Native devleopment environment inside docker?

Tags: react-native, docker

Let me first mention that we have three dockers for development and they are awesome.

One for React, One for Nextjs, and one for .NET.

All a developer in our team has to do, is to install linux (we force OS), git and nginx and docker, VS Code, and our shell scripts. That's it. And asides from Linux, the rest is totally automated. He only installs Linux, and then runs one script that takes care of everything.

Then he can run our own shell script commands and start developing any application he wants.

In other words, there is no need to install .NET, Node, SQL Server, etc.

Now, based on these experiences, we wanted to start coding [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

And to our shock, it seems that installing and configuring it inside a docker container is not possible.

But I wanted to ask the community, because this first step is very crucial in our success. We did a lot of work to reduce development environment setup for our tech stack, and if we are forced to leave it for React Native, then that's a fail for us.

Can we develop react inside a docker container? Can we at least build it inside a container and do not install Android Studio and XCode on each developer's machine?

Comment: YES, its posible.

Comment: Extra points for enforcement Linux usage. React native is just a nodejs application with a lot and complex packages. React native in your developer machines will work in dev mode with linux and docker. The build mode is another story. Builds for android will work on your linux and also with docker. Builds for ios is not possible due to the private nature of apple. I tried and I could not achieve it. Is this your problem?

Comment: Did you get more information about this?

Comment: @LautaroZarandon, no, I just quit becoming a react native developer :D.